# how do i iterate a cursor in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo

i am currently working on a project and i have created two collections in my mongodb .
i want to be able to get a particular field out of the collection
here is the code

`app = mongo.db.apps
find_app = app.find({'email':session['email']})
x = []
for apps in find_app:
    x.append(apps)
print(x)`

this prints [{'_id': ObjectId('5bb07458e58fb90fc8a60d49'), 'email': 'celviuks@ge.com', 'app_name': 'apply', 'version': '1'}, 
{'_id': ObjectId('5bb0795ae58fb90c18bf7f5e'), 'email': 'celvius@egg.com', 'app_name': 'egg', 'version': '1'}]

and i want only the app_name field
please how to i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved it with less code

```
app = mongo.db.apps
find_app = app.find({'email':session['email']}, {app_name: 1, _id: 0})
done_apps = [doc['appname'] for doc in find_app]
return render_template('somepage.html',done_apps=done_apps)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app = mongo.db.apps

find_app = app.find({'email':session['email']}, 
                    {app_name: 1, _id: 0})

x = []
for apps in find_app:
    x.append(apps)

print(x)
```